# MMT is an application layer in OSI model or in IP/TCP model?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg

In all papers related to Mpeg media transport, it is written that it is an application layer transport protocols.I was wondering if it is an application layer protocol in OSI model or in IP/TCP model?

Comment: Can you point these papers?

Comment: fore example in these two : "New MPEG Transport Standard for Next Generation Hybrid Broadcasting System with IP" and "Overview on MPEG MMT Technology and Its Application to Hybrid Media Delivery over Heterogeneous Networks"